How to rename the putput from a remote system query to reflect the remote system name?
I'm just wondering if anyone can help me with this?
I'm pulling a list of installed software from a group of remote systems on the network, and was wondering if there was a way to have the individual outputs reflect the name of the remote system?
Update:
I now have it outputting the remote system host-name to a single file, but now im stuck trying to figure out how i get it to output each remote system name contained in the computer.txt file to a separate file
Cheers
Pete
This is the script I'm using:
$cred = Get-Credential
    $computers = Get-Content "C:\computers\computers.txt"
        $computers | ForEach-Object{
            Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:    \SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |      Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |               Format-Table –AutoSize |  Out-File -Append -FilePath c:\temp\asset.txt
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-    Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize |  Out-File -Append -FilePath c:\temp\asset.txt

}
Rename-Item -Path "c:\temp\asset.txt" -NewName "C:\temp$($env:COMPUTERNAME).txt"

I should have said im running the script via Powershell
